# Blue Prism calendar

Tags: calendar, blueprism

What should I put in the calendar name

and where is it configured, how can I change the calendar?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of calendars is in the settings:

[image]

If you have a custom calendar, you will have to create it and use that name in your action instead. Currently, using 'Working Week / No Holidays' as the calendar name will work for that particular calendar.

Comment: @Javi you mean you *didn't* see it?